# Does G5 organic silica increases significantly the level of collagen produced by human fibroblasts?

Tags: tendinopathy, natural-remedy, collagen

http://www.siliciumg5.com/en/online-shop/12-silicium-g5-gel-8437006679022.html states that:

> A study has shown that G5 organic silica increases significantly the level of collagen produced by human fibroblasts, up to 19% compared with the control. In the trials carried out, G5 organic silica showed no cytotoxicity. Other studies confirm the effectiveness in a great range of conditions of applying the G5 gel along with regular doses of G5 Siliplant.

However, the website fails to give the references to these studies, and searching on Google Scholar was unsuccessful.

Does  G5 organic silica increases significantly the level of collagen produced by human fibroblasts?

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.